# Twitter API: timestamp out of Bounds when calling oauth request_token

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am trying to integrate the oauth flow in my application.

I am getting a 401 when calling the oauth/request_token endpoint with this error:

```
"message": "401 - {\"errors\":[{\"code\":135,\"message\":\"Timestamp out of bounds.\"}]}"
```

This is my authorization header:

```
"Authorization": "OAuth oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Ftwitter%2Foauth_callback,oauth_consumer_key=MYKEY,oauth_nonce=150255341200200,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_timestamp=1502553412002,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_signature=d09f2f2a39e51909442ae6ca717e4aeba7066fda"
```

I can see in the response header that the server time for Twitter is:`“date”: “Sat, 12 Aug 2017 15:56:52 GMT”`

If I take my timestamp and convert it to a GMT date I get:

```
Saturday, August 12, 2017 3:56:52.002 PM
```

I am not sure why it is considered out of bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oauth_timestamp should be the number of **whole** seconds since 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Your timestamp is out by a factor of around 1000! It should have been:

```
oauth_timestamp=1502553412
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the library I was using was faulty. Figured it out later, but your answer was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For timestamp value, please use the below piece of code:

```
Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```